# Multi-Step campaign or Salesforce approval process on Exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, campaign

I need to create multi-step campaign on Exacttarget.

Requirements:

I send survey email (step1) to my users by email and **depending on response**, reply with step2.a or step2.b, and so on...

I didn't find out how to do so on Exacttarget UI. 
But, luckily, today I have seen this [article](https://na12.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/approvals_creating_approval_steps.htm) on Salesforce that meets my requirements.

But, does it possible on Exacttarget?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is exactly the basis for the ExactTarget Journey Builder application, which you may wish to investigate.  If you really only need a simple solution (and not looking to build a long series are triggered event), you can set up a landing page that posts when you click submit on the survey.  On this landing page, you have the code to do several different triggered sends, and have the conditional logic there to "trigger" the desired email.

Hope this helps!